# Refs are empty in a form container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is have a Form react component which has a couple methods to check if all the input elements inside are valid.

What I've tried is the following:

```
var FormContainer = React.createClass({
        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {
                elements: []
            };
        },
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                errors: {}
            };
        },
        className: function() {
            return 'form-container';
        },
        isValid: function() {
            var valid = true,
            self = this;

            this.props.elements.forEach(function(ref){
                if (!self.refs[ref].isValid()){
                    valid = false;
                }
            });

            return valid;
        },
        render: function() {
            var self = this;

            return (
                <form className={self.className()}>
                    {self.props.children}

                    <span>Things be valid: </span> <span>{self.isValid()}</span>
                </form>
            );
        }
    });
```

And it has an Input type as well:

```
var Input = React.createClass({
        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {
                type: 'text'
            };
        },
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {

            };
        },
        className: function() {
            return 'form-input';
        },
        isValid: function() {
            return false;
        },
        render: function() {
            var self = this;

            return (
                <input type={self.props.type} className={self.className()} />
            );
        }
    });
```

And then this is how I would implement it:

```
<Form elements={["date"]}>
    <Input ref="date" type="date"></Input>
</Form>
```

The magic happens in the FormContainer `isValid` method. What I want to do is for each input name thats added to the `elements` array, to be able to get the reference to it and call it's own `isValid` method.

However I see that self.refs is empty when I try to call it here if `(!self.refs[ref].isValid())`. I'm new to React so I'm not quite sure I understand the refs bit, but I thought that any Children of my `<Form>` that had a ref would be able to be accessed through the `<Form>` itself. How can I fix this or do it a better way? The point is to gather up all the child elements and check their validity in one place at the `Form` level.

Comment: `refs` require a named element (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), so that doesn't seem like a match for what you're trying to do.

Comment: You might consider using `React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function (child) { /* your code here  */ });` in the `isValid` function. There you could loop through all children and query for their validity state (if they are a component that has that property of course).

Comment: I would like to avoid recursively searching through the child nodes if possible (since there can be nested input elements inside structural divs or something).

Comment: You'll either need to bubble state outward via events or recursively scan inward (or a dispatcher, but validation info doesn't seem like something you'd put in a store).

Comment: @WiredPrairie React.Children.forEach isn't recursive right? How do I search the children recursively?

Comment: also, i can't seem to call methods on the children using react.children.foreach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code *works*. Your problem is that when `isValid()` is called

```
<span>Things be valid: </span> <span>{self.isValid()}</span>
```

React hasn't finished parsing the structure yet and thus `this.refs` will be an empty object which is why you should refrain from checking `this.refs` inside the `render()` function.

The [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) are quite clear about this.

*Never access refs inside of any component's render method - or while any component's render method is even running anywhere in the call stack.*

I would move the `isValid()` functionality to be used when either submitting or actually manipulating the form.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/9599/)